# Ajax doesnt send data to php script

Tags: php, ajax

I want to send id to php script.I think my code is ok, but when i click on  tag i get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\domaci\cao.php on line 4
```

here is my html + ajax code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">       
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('a').click(function(){
                $.post($(this).attr('href'), { id : $(this).attr('id') } );
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="cao.php" id="Barselona" >Barselona</a>
        </br>
        <a href="cao.php" id="Beograd" >Beograd</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is cao.php:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php 
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            echo $id;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

i really need this to get to work, please help me :)

Comment: The click will cause the browser to follow the link, you have to handle it and stop it

Answer (score 1):

Your `$.post` ajax is fine. The issue is when the anchor is clicked, you don't preventDefault or return false, to stop the browser redirecting to `cao.php`. When it redirects to `cao.php`, it is a GET request, and so triggers the undefined index notice because there is no post data.

Add return false or preventDefault:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr('href'), { id : $(this).attr('id') } );
});
```

Look at your browser's console (F12) on the Network tab, to see the response of the ajax.

Comment: when i add e.preventdefault and i click on <a> tag i stay on my html page

Comment: i looked in console and i think ajax is ok, is there ant other way to redirect on next page beside <a>

Answer (score 0):

Try it now.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $.post($(this).attr('data-url'), { id : $(this).attr('id') } );
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" data-url="cao.php" id="Barselona" >Barselona</a>
</br>
<a href="#" data-url="cao.php" id="Beograd" >Beograd</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: url is not a valid attribute on a link. You'll have to use a data attribute: 'data-url'. It's also recognized by jQuery, so that you can just use $(this).data('url')

Answer (score 0):

Your link redirects you, so simpe do this:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Also its better to have variables (for future), here is [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JV7XR/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one will work for you:

```
<html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">       
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('a').click(function(){
                    $.post('cao.php', { id : $(this).attr('id') },function(data){
                        alert(data);
                     });
                });
            });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <a href="#" id="Barselona" >Barselona</a>
            </br>
            <a href="#" id="Beograd" >Beograd</a>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**AT cao.php page**

```
<?php 
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            echo $id;die;
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

just try print_r($_POST) in cao.php & check the values are posting

```
$id=$_POST["id"];
```